# jquery changing the href attribute of an anchor link

Tags: jquery

I have a link whose href attribute should be changed based upon the radio button option selected. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTFf6/22/) is the link to the code

I see that the href attribute is changed via firebug, but when clicked upon, it does not go to the new link. What could be the issue here?

The HTML:

```
<a id="urlTest" title="Checkout" href="yahoo.com">Checkout</a>

<p><input type="radio" value="www.apple.com" name="url">Change to apple</p>

<p><input type="radio" value="www.google.com" name="url">Change to google</p>
```

The JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=url]').bind('click', function () {
        $("#urlTest").attr("href",$(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript is invalid; you're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the `bind` parameter list. Errors like this are visible in the console (including on jsfiddle).

The domain names should be fully-qualified, too.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input[name=url]').click(function () { 
        $("#urlTest").attr("href",$(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

You were missing the ending parenthesis.

Also use fully qualified domain names with http.

You can also use the shorthand version: `.click(function () {})` instead of `.bind('click', function () {})`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input[name=url]').click(function(){
    $("#urlTest").attr("href",$(this).val());
})
```

It works for me.

Comment: Arent you missing a semicolon? (so its sure to parse every test)